# How to parse javascript variable array embedded in http://up-for-grabs.net/#/?

Tags: javascript, powershell, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to parse http://up-for-grabs.net/#/ to get its content in CSV file using powershell. I have written below code till now

```
$URL = "http://up-for-grabs.net/#/"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL
$script_blocks = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("script") | Where{ $_.type -eq ‘text/javascript’ }

$content = ""
foreach ($script_block in $script_blocks)
{
    if($script_block.innerHTML -ne $null -and `
       $script_block.innerHTML.trim().StartsWith("var files"))
    {
       $content = $script_block.innerHTML.trim()
    }
 }
```

Looking further in the content, it seems like a variable array embedded in JavaScript whose initial lines are formatted as follows. Its array with no spaces or new lines which are my creation to improve readability.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var files = {

  "aspnet-razor-4":{"name":"ASP.NET Razor 4","desc":"Parser and code generator for CSHTML files used in view pages for MVC web apps.","site":"https://github.com/aspnet/Razor","tags":["Microsoft","ASP.NET","Razor","MVC"], "upforgrabs":{"name":"up-for-grabs","link":"https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/labels/up-for-grabs"}},

  "fsharpdatadbpedia":{"name":"FSharp.Data.DbPedia","desc":"FSharp.Data.DbPedia - An F# type provider for DBpedia","site":"https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.DbPedia","tags":[".NET","DbPedia","F#"],"upforgrabs":{"name":"up-for-grabs","link":"https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.DbPedia/labels/up-for-grabs"}},

  "makesharp":{"name":"Make#","desc":"Use C# scripts to automate the building process","site":"https://github.com/sapiens/MakeSharp","tags":[".Net","C#","make","build","automation","tools"],"upforgrabs":{"name":"up-for-grabs","link":"https://github.com/sapiens/MakeSharp/labels/up-for-grabs"}},

  "stateprinter":{"name":"StatePrinter","desc":"Automating unittest asserts and ToString() coding.","site":"https://github.com/kbilsted/StatePrinter","tags":["TDD","Unit Testing","TDD",".NET","C#","ToString","Debugging"],"upforgrabs":{"name":"Help wanted","link":"https://github.com/kbilsted/StatePrinter/labels/Help%20wanted"}}

</script>
```

This immediately is followed by

```
var projects = new Array();

for (var fileName in files) {
    projects.push(files[fileName]);
}
```

How can I achieve similar quick parsing in powershell without writing big code with string tokenization.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I figured out that this is a JSON content for which powershell cmdlet [ConvertFrom-Json](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx) needs to be used. I do not want to copy the whole script here. Please look at [this GitHub location](https://github.com/AtulKumar2/PowershellScripts/blob/master/Up-For-Grabs.net.ps1) to see how to use this cmdlet effectively. Basically, you need to remember that object returned by this cmdlet is a custom object which need to be enumerated to get various properties. Its not an array, so only foreach will work to uncover the content. A small code sample is below

```
$file_json = $file_string | ConvertFrom-Json
$delim = " ; "

foreach ($item in $file_json | gm)
{
    $props = $file_json.$($item.Name)
    if($props.MemberType) {continue}

    $row = $props.name.ToString()
    $row += $delim + $props.desc.ToString()
    $row += $delim + $props.site.ToString()
}
```

Searching for this cmdlet on web will give you more details on how to deal with this conversion.